# Restrict search of locate to specific directories

Tags: osx, search, locate

Is there a way to restrict `locate` output to specific directories on Mac OS X Snow Leopard? I read about using regex on a Ubuntu forum. However, on my mac `locate` does not accept `-r` option. I also looked at the `man` pages for locate on Mac and there is no `-r` option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use shell wildcards in the locate's search pattern - that functionality is a historical feature of the utility and should be supported on all systems.

E.g.:

```
$ locate '*/dirname/*filename*'
```

Be sure to use stars around the search string (or at least in front of it) as once you use wildcards `locate` switches the logic and anchors the search string to beginning and end of the searched material.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install another version of locate. I do not have a OS X system to check, but it seems that slocate is present in macports, so it should be quite easy to install, and I think it does have the required option.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mdfind` instead.

```
$ mdfind -onlyin $HOME iTunes
```

The `md`* utilities use the same database as **Spotlight**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mix it with the `grep` command, like:

```
locate hosts | grep ^/etc
```

or:

```
locate php | grep -e ^/etc -e ^/usr/local/etc
```

to look into multiple directories.

If you using this functionality very often, write a wrapper for it.